# Query results to temp, then move to mast table

Tags: sql, sql-insert, temp-tables

I don't know what I am doing. Extra new at this. Below I am trying to make corrections to the data on a column, with out losing any of the data, just overriding it. In this Column, some of the cells have characters spaces (spacebar) in them so it dose not show up as "NULL".

In my fist attempt, I can see the query data and it looks good, 100% correct. But don't know how to put that data into the table I got it from. So I need to replace the data in column 'Speedlink_IP' with my Queried results.

Thanks every one in advance!

1st Attempt -

```
SELECT NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(Speedlink_IP)), '')
    As Speedlink_IP
    FROM Master_IP_Data
    INSERT INTO TEMP1 (col1)
```

2nd attempt -

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP1 (
        col1 varchar (50) NULL
        );


    SELECT NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(Speedlink_IP)), '')
    As Speedlink_IP
    FROM Master_IP_Data
    INSERT INTO TEMP1 (col1)

INSERT INTO dbo.Master_IP_Data (Speedlink_IP)
    SELECT col1
    FROM TEMP1
;

DROP Table TEMP1
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.  Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag are helpful.  Your self-assessment is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE Master_IP_Data 
SET Speedlink_IP = NULL
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Speedlink_IP)) = ''
```

This query will turn to `NULL` values of `Speedlink_IP` that contains only spaces. You don't need to use a temporary table for this.